# Audio issues, cutting out and random loud noises the more things it has to process

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I'm stuggling with audio problems with Ubuntu on my desktop PC, when audio skips and paused and sometimes dies completely and produces loud static. If all I'm doing it watching youtube things are usually ok.

But if I play a game, or do multiple tasks where multiple sounds are being mixed I get the problems more frequently. Restarting alsa or pulse fixes nothing, all I can do is reboot the system or switch between HDMI and optical a few times and it goes away.

I'm using HDMI on my NVidia card using proprietary drivers.

I used this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log to produce a log here: http://pastebin.com/h5aU5beh http://pastebin.com/xdvb4eAf http://pastebin.com/tVX1fgJv

All I did was to run the commands, load Planetary Annihilation through steam, get the skipping problem and save the output. I can't see much in there myself.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

- The 3rd log shows audio underuns  in Pulseaudio due  to high cpu load, so i would try to disable   Pulseaudio to see if  Alsa only is better :

  - Run this 2 commands in terminal:
    echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf
    pulseaudio -k
    This will stop pulseaudio, then relaunch your software and test .
    You can set alsa layer volume   with alsamixer in a terminal or installing gnome-alsamixer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I get the same thing with ALSA, what could be causing the load on the CPU? And can I get an ALSA log to help debug this?

Comment: Cpu load is from the games or flash  video.You use hdmi audio, is it the same problem on internal soundcard?   When you say "same thing with alsa " , did you try removing pulseaudio ? If no,for test purpose, I would try   to remove it (`sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio` then reboot and test )  . To reinstall it: sudo apt-get install  pulseaudio  and/or sudo apt-get install  unity

Comment: In Ubuntu 14 this seems to kill Unity, removing pulse also removes most of the system settings. I cannot get Audio to work at all through the ALSA Mixer but you've given me a lot to play with. Thanks! Also I have checked and my CPU and RAM usage is well bellow 30% when I'm getting these issues. What I meant was why is the audio not getting enough of CPU to run smoothly? Rather than what is using my CPU: the game. http://pigsearengineering.com/uploads/3/3/5/6/3356657/header_images/cpu-load.png